# How to set height of child div while hovering over a parent div in css?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a drop-down menu that I want to display a submenu when you hover over one of the main menus. All of the `child_menus` have an initial height of 0. My HTML is roughly as follows...

```
<div class = "parent_menu">Parent 1
    <a href = "link"><div class = "child_menu">Child 1 text</div></a>
    <a href = "link"><div class = "child_menu">Child 2 text</div></a>
</div>

<div class = "parent_menu">Parent 2
    <a href = "link"><div class = "child_menu">Child 1 text</div></a>
    <a href = "link"><div class = "child_menu">Child 2 text</div></a>
</div>
```

I know that you can set properties with the `:hover` selector, but can I do something like `.parent_menu:hover THEN FIND .child_menu {height:auto;}`

By the way I know I can do it in JavaScript, but there has to be a way in CSS too.

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle link to your code in issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/r83FD/1/

```
.parent_menu div {    
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.parent_menu:hover div {
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I like you fiddle more then my own, because I forgot to set overflow hidden. Well done.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed, but couldn't quite figure out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might mean something like this:

```
.parent_menu:hover .child_menu {
  height: auto;
}
```

Try a demo of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/M4NUP/

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it should work

```
.parent_menu:hover a.child_menu{
  height:auto;
}
```